# DateTime getDayOfYear() Returning 366 for 12-31-2013 instead of 365

Tags: java, datetime

Does anyone know why this method is behaving this way?  2013 is not a leap year, so I would expect that if I have a DateTime object like:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");         
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2013-12-31 23:59:52");
```

That

```
    dt.getDayOfYear()
```

would give me 365 but it's giving me 366.  Can anyone see what the problem is?
I am also getting 366 if I do

```
    dt.toString("DDD");
```

I would appreciate any input anyone might have.

Comment: This may be a Timezone problem, in which case we need @JonSkeet.

Comment: It would be good if you post your timezone as well.

Comment: I am using TimeZone UTC.  So the last minute of the last day of the year in UTC time.  Does this help?

Comment: Also, the DateTime is being created from a TimeStamp retrieved from a database.  If I print out the raw DateTime, it shows: 2013-12-31T23:59:52.000Z

Comment: @Quirliom, best comment in weeks (Shangai)!

Comment: Is it DateTimeFormatter from Java8 or from Joda (not that I am sure it matters, just to be sure not to walk in the wrong direction.)

Comment: I believe it's from Joda.  I'm not actually using the formatter.  It was just an example.  I am creating the DateTime object from a TimeStamp retrieved from a database that is storing it in UTC time.

Comment: So how do you make the DateTime then from the timestamp and which DateTime is it? Which package?

Comment: I am using Joda Time 2.1.  I create the DateTime Object like this:  DateTime date = (new DateTime(rs.getTimestamp("column_Name"))).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));

Comment: rs from above is the resultSet from the database...

Comment: Oh date hell, I might have an explanation, depending on what your local time zone is.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try an answer based on what I read from the docs and the code.

I assume your time stamp is indeed what you think it is, namely that last minute of 2013 UTC.

You create a `DateTime` object with the stamp **in the default timezone**. So if your local time zone is +01:00, this is `2013-14-01 00:59 +01:00`.

Now you use `withZoneRetainFields(UTC)`. From the docs I understand that this changes the milliseconds such that they actually reflect `2014-01-01 00:59 UTC`, Basically this requires to add 3600*1000 millis to the time stamp, while changing the time zone entry in the object to UTC.

When you then ask for the day of the year, what actually happens internally is

`.dayOfYear().get(getMillis())`

My hunch is that `dayOfYear` is still based on 2013 and from this baseline you get day 366.

(I am not totally convinced myself of this answer I must admit and I wonder if there might be simply a bug lurking in Joda.)

Anyway: if you have UTC timestamps, I might suggest to just use new `DateTime(stamp, UTC)` where `UTC` a `DateTimeZone` object. Thereby you avoid the mind-bending double zone shifting.
EDIT: Further, if your stamp from the DB is genuinely UTC, by using`withZoneRetainFields` you change that stamp to denote another point in time, which has a good chance of being the wrong way to do whatever you are actually trying to do. In the confusing area of date/time handling, the time stamp in millis is the one easy to understand item. If it is not just for display purposes, I would never touch it.

Comment: Thank you @Harald.  This does somewhat demystify it if it is in fact what is happening.  I will at least try your last suggestion and see if it alters the results in any way (and I will post any results I get).  I was wondering myself if there could be a bug lurking in Joda.

Comment: Thanks @Harald.  Just saw your edit.  I am getting a new mystery.  I am trying to get epoch time for each minute of the day on 12/25/2013.  Everything is fine except for minutes 1140-1154 (19 hours in to the day).  They are off by 1 day each.  So for minute 1139 I have epoch time 1388015940, which is correct.  Then minutes 1140 jumps to 1387929600.  From 1140-1154, they are incremented by 60 seconds, which is correct, but all off by one day.  Then at minute 1155, they go back to the correct time of 1388016900.  Any reason you can think of for this?

Comment: From the way you write a date, I guess you are living in the US. And from the strange behavior at 19 hours I further guess you are in the -05:00 timezone, somewhere at the east cost. Clearly you are somehow caught the behavior of local date/time objects. Please consider creating only DateTime objects with a specific time zone already specified in the constructor.